# WebStorm shortcut to open in browser doesn't work

Tags: ide, shortcut, webstorm

The WebStorm shortcut `alt + shift + b` to open a file in the browser doesn't work. It's annoying to do this by mouse.

I set the IDE setting or whatever that was to Visual Studio when installing WebStorm.

Any idea how to get that shortcut working (or some other shortcut to acheive the same task)?

Comment: 1) `Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | Keymap` -- you can check what other actions may have the same shortcut and assign any other shortcut in case of duplicates/non working; 2) you may have some app that intercepts that shortcut globally (i.e. some instant messenger or video driver app); 3) Maybe you are calling this action from wrong context (which window/area in IDE is active) -- possible, but sounds unlikely since it's working when invoked with mouse, as I understand.

Comment: 4) The `Alt+Shift+B` shortcut has nothing to do with opening your **file** in a browser -- in `Visual Studio` keymap it is associated with "Open **Task** in Browser" action.